# Validating Ecto "many-to-many" relationships

Tags: validation, associations, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to determine the right way to validate a many-to-many relationship in Ecto 2.  I have a Conversation model that needs to have many members, and Users can be part of many conversations, so I've established the models like so:

```
# User Model
defmodule MyApp.User do

  ...

  schema "users" do
    ....

    many_to_many :conversations, Conversation, join_through: "conversations_users"

    ...
  end

  ...
end

# Conversation Model
defmodule MyApp.Conversation do
  ...

  schema "conversations" do
    has_many :messages, Message
    many_to_many :members, User, join_through: "conversations_users"

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, _params) do
    struct
    |> validate_member_count
  end   

  defp validate_member_count(changeset) do
    members = Repo.all(assoc(changeset, :members))
    valid? = length(members) == 2

    if valid? do
      add_error(changeset, :members, "foo")
    else
      changeset
    end
  end
end
```

However, I just can't get this to work.  I've written a simple test to verify that the validations run correctly, but I keep getting the following error:

```
# Test
test "fails to validate a conversation with less than two members" do
  changeset = Conversation.changeset(%Conversation{}, %{})

  {message, []} = changeset.errors[:members]
  assert message === "must have at least two members"
end
```

> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Changeset.add_error/4

I'm having a hard time understanding what I'm doing wrong. It seems like it can't find the function, but I've checked the documentation and it seems like `Ecto.Changeset.add_error/4` is definitely right, and the arguments to it seem correct as well.

My best guess is that I need to do something in the validation before calling my custom validator, but I just don't know what I should do.

Comment: Try replacing `struct |> validate_member_count` with `struct |> change |> validate_member_count` in `MyApp.Conversation.changeset/2`.

Comment: I get a different error now:

`** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Ecto.Changeset.__schema__/2 is undefined or private`

Comment: Try replacing `Repo.all(assoc(changeset, :members))` with `Repo.all(assoc(changeset.data, :members))`.

Comment: Yes! That did it! Thanks so much.  Please submit a proper answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes:

1. You're passing a `MyApp.Conversation` to `validate_member_count`, not an `Ecto.Changeset`. You can convert an Ecto Schema defining Struct into an `Ecto.Changeset` using `Ecto.Changeset.change/1`:

   ```
   def changeset(struct, _params) do
     struct
     |> change
     |> validate_member_count
   end
   ```
2. `Ecto.assoc/2` accepts an Ecto Schema Struct, not an `Ecto.Changeset`. You can access the underlying struct from an `Ecto.Changeset` using `.data`:

   ```
   members = Repo.all(assoc(changeset.data, :members))
   ```

Final code:

```
def changeset(struct, _params) do
  struct
  |> change
  |> validate_member_count
end

defp validate_member_count(changeset) do
  members = Repo.all(assoc(changeset.data, :members))
  valid? = length(members) == 2

  if valid? do
    add_error(changeset, :members, "foo")
  else
    changeset
  end
end
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!